# Help with 2 contour integrals on a curve $\gamma_1$ which is the unit circle centered at $z=0$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve these 2 integrals but I don't know how.

$$\oint_{\gamma_{1}} \cosh{(a(z+\frac{1}z))} \,dz$$
$$\oint_{\gamma_{1}} \cos{(a(z+\frac{1}z))} \,dz$$

$\gamma_1$ is the unit circle centered at $z=0$. Is the result of the integrals a holomorphic function of
the parameter $a$?

It would be very helpful for me if you could explain me how to solve it. I found it a bit hard to integrate directly...

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the unit circle we have that $z^{-1} = \bar{z}$ so we can rewrite the integral as

$$\int_{\gamma_1} \cosh(a(z+\bar{z}))\:dz$$

Then we can use the following theorem:

$$\int_{\partial \Omega} f\:dz = 2i\iint_\Omega \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}\:dx\wedge dy$$

This means the integral is equivalent to

$$2i a \iint_D \sinh(z+\bar{z})\:dx\wedge dy = 2i a \iint_D \sinh(2x)\:dx\wedge dy = 0$$

by odd symmetry. And since the second integral is equivalent to the first by absorbing a factor of $i$ into the $a$, they both evaluate to $0$

Comment: Very useful! What is that theorem? I've never heard of that one. It's simillar to the Stokes Theorem... where did you find it?

Comment: @EmpressofLight I haven't been successful in finding a reference for it online except for a generalization of it in Cauchy's integral formula. You can prove it by splitting up $f = u+iv$, $dz = x+ idy$ cross multiplying then using the real valued 2$D$ Green's theorem on the real and imaginary pieces separately

Comment: The theorem then follows from the definition $$2\partial_{\bar{z}} = \partial_x + i\partial_y$$